# NGINX throwing '403 Forbidden' when 'root' is changed

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, centos7

fresh centos7.4 has been installed. No PHP or mySQL has been installed yet. Only NGINX is installed.

'/etc/nginx/nginx.conf' file is untouched.

'/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf' is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name public_IP private_IP;

    # note that these lines are originally from the "location /" block
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

}
```

Everything works fine...
[image]

but when I change the configuration to...

```
...
root /var/www/html;
...
```

it throws error:
[image]

I already have commanded:

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www
sudo chown -R nginx:nginx /var/wwww
```

but not works.

Comment: do you have any files there?

Comment: yes, I've index.html, test.html files in the location /var/www/html, server_ip/*.* nothing is accessible

Comment: Considering this is CentOS, you might want to check the SElinux permissions as well. Try `ls -alZ /var/www` and the context should be something similar to `system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0` for public web content.

Answer (score 0):

If you have tried all the ways and did not succeed, this way can help you:

check status SELinux

`sestatus`

if enabled:

`# getenforce`

`# setenforce Permissive`

and end

`sudo systemctl restart nginx`